# Pushing Git repo through SSH chain

Tags: github, ssh, ftp, sftp, githooks

I just started a new job, which is trying to start using Git for version control. I am trying to help them with the process but it is turning out to be more complicated than anticipated.

Currently, all new files are uploaded to the dev server via SSH FTP as follows:

SSH into first machine, then SSH from here into the actual Dev server.

Ideally, we'd like to be able to be able to enter "git push dev" and have git skip through both SSH to push the files to the Dev server... However, I'm not sure how to add a sequence of origins to Git...

Does anyone know if this is possible, or how one might go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you familiar with [`ProxyCommand`](http://www.statusq.org/archives/2008/07/03/1916/) ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Adding solution reference for other folks looking https://wiki.fd.io/view/DEV/Chaining_Git_Over_SSH